# Angular ngIf: form field alert condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I've create this `ngIf` condition under a field form:

```
<div class="with-errors error-missatge"
    *ngIf="expirationdate.dirty && !expirationdate.errors?.dateTime?.future">
    {{ 'ui.errors.field.datetime.future' | translate }}
</div>
```

Condition is: `expirationdate.dirty && !expirationdate.errors?.dateTime?.future`.

Problem appears when `expirationdate.errors is`null`. Then seems that condition is`true`.

I need that when no `expirationdate.errors` is defined then whole condition is `false`.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Use the condition,

```
expirationdate.dirty && expirationdate.errors && !expirationdate.errors?.dateTime?.future
```